# Как узнать в каком элементе массива нужный мне ID?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть пример кода,в массиве alarms  5 елементов, как мне узнать в каком элементе массива есть id "66425d90-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e "?(в

```html
alarms: Array(5)
  [0 … 5]
  0:
    ackTs: 0
    clearTs: 0
    createdTime: 1541499120105
    details: {}
    endTs: 1541499120101
    id: {entityType: "ALARM", id: "**66425d90-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e**"}
    name: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    originator: {entityType: "DEVICE", id: "a37a3610-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"}
    originatorName: "Силос 5"
    propagate: true
    severity: "CRITICAL"
    startTs: 1541499120101
    status: "ACTIVE_UNACK"
    tenantId: {entityType: "TENANT", id: "209302e0-db67-11e8-9cd5-d98fbfb5c39f"}
    type: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    __proto__: Object
  1:
    ackTs: 0
    clearTs: 0
    createdTime: 1541499120055
    details: {}
    endTs: 1541499120052
    id: {entityType: "ALARM", id: "663abc70-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"}
    name: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    originator: {entityType: "DEVICE", id: "975a1da0-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"}
    originatorName: "Силос 4"
    propagate: true
    severity: "CRITICAL"
    startTs: 1541499120052
    status: "ACTIVE_UNACK"
    tenantId: {entityType: "TENANT", id: "209302e0-db67-11e8-9cd5-d98fbfb5c39f"}
    type: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    __proto__: Object
  2:
    ackTs: 0
    clearTs: 0
    createdTime: 1541499120020
    details: {}
    endTs: 1541499120016
    id: {entityType: "ALARM", id: "66356540-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"}
    name: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    originator: {entityType: "DEVICE", id: "93536270-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e"}
    originatorName: "Силос 3"
    propagate: true
    severity: "CRITICAL"
    startTs: 1541499120016
    status: "ACTIVE_UNACK"
    tenantId: {entityType: "TENANT", id: "209302e0-db67-11e8-9cd5-d98fbfb5c39f"}
    type: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено"
    __proto__: Object
  3: {id: {…}, createdTime: 1541499119984, tenantId: {…}, type: "Пристрій     "SmartScale" відключено", originator: {…}, …}
  4: {id: {…}, createdTime: 1541499119935, tenantId: {…}, type: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено", originator: {…}, …}
  5: {id: {…}, createdTime: 1541496660084, tenantId: {…}, type: "Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено", originator: {…}, …}
```

Comment: `alarms.findIndex(i => i.id === '66425d90-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e');`

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно найти непосредственно элемент тогда в масиве **alarms**

```
const alarms = [{
  ackTs: 0,
  clearTs: 0,
  createdTime: 1541499120105,
  details: {},
  endTs: 1541499120101,
  id: {entityType: 'ALARM', id: '66425d90-e1ac-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e'},
  name: 'Пристрій  "SmartScale" відключено',
  originator: {entityType: 'DEVICE', id: 'a37a3610-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e'},
  originatorName: 'Силос 5',
  propagate: true,
  ...
},
  ...
];
```

тогда

```
const result = alarms.find(alarm => alarm.id.id === 'a37a3610-db67-11e8-b1fa-1d0c2fbc6b3e');
```